# What is a word for someone who genuinely believes they are wise but others do not agree?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase that could describe someone who has spent a lot of time learning some form of wisdom, yet the word or phrase must reflect the fact that the person writing the description does not believe that wisdom to be truly enlightening.

In short, I'm looking for the equivalent of the following sentence, but without the need for scare quotes:

She has spent time growing "wise" from their writings.

Target sentence (which can include prepositions or other words aside from the line if necessary):

"She has spent time _____ing their writings."

Thank you.

Comment: You're gonna have to write a sentence and leave a blank where you want the requested word to go. That's how single-word requests are  done here.

Comment: A phrase used to describe this situation is **'They're too clever by half.'**
From [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/too_clever_by_half): PHRASE ... 

informal ... (of a person) _annoyingly proud of their intelligence or skill, and liable to overreach themselves_
‘he always was too clever by half’ // [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/too_clever_by_half) has: 'Shrewd but flawed by overthinking or excessive complexity, with a resulting tendency to be unreliable or unsuccessful.'

Comment: Generally, this person would be called a *fool*.

Comment: i’d say they are ***conceited***

Comment: You might consider *deluded* - although it has a much wider reach.

Comment: A "Polonius," perhaps?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have edited the post to make it clearer as to what I'm looking for. (I hope I've done this correctly - as you can tell, I'm new here.)

Comment: She is an example of the Dunning-Kruger effect, which is where people overestimate their expertise precisely because they don't have enough expertise to make an accurate assessment.

Answer (score 4):

*Sophomoric* fits, I think. From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sophomoric):

1. conceited and overconfident of knowledge but poorly informed and immature • a *sophomoric* argument